# how can you render an HTML array?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I have an array with `<p>` and `<div>` items and I'm trying to render them as HTML, but whenever I try to render it, the values just appear as plain code and not the normal paragraphs. So I have an array with let's say that this information:

```
<p>The first paragraph of this pinned topic will be visible as a welcome message to all new visitors on your homepage. It’s important!</p>
<p><strong>Edit this</strong> into a brief description of your community:</p>
```

And when it gets rendered in the page, it gets rendered as this instead of the paragraph that should be rendered it gets rendered as plain code:

[this is how it renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ysGq.png)

This is the code I've used for render:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/get-post?id=${pid}`)
    .then(res => setPostData(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
  }, [])
console.log(postData?.post_stream?.posts[0]?.cooked)
  return (
    <div>
        <div className={styles.containerPadding}>
            <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
                <div className={styles.blackLine}>

                </div>
                <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <div>
                        <h1>{postData.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.postInformationContainer}>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>{postData?.post_stream?.posts[0]?.cooked}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for converting your string data to HTML, but for safety (avoiding [XSS attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)), you should sanitize your HTML string before using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` by [`DOMPurify`](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'

const sanitizedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(postData?.post_stream?.posts[0]?.cooked)
```

And then call it like this

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitizedHtml}}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/get-post?id=${pid}`)
    .then(res => setPostData(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
  }, [])
const sanitizedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(postData?.post_stream?.posts[0]?.cooked)
  return (
    <div>
        <div className={styles.containerPadding}>
            <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
                <div className={styles.blackLine}>

                </div>
                <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <div>
                        <h1>{postData.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.postInformationContainer}>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitizedHtml}}></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

One side note, without HTML string sanitization, your HTML data can be interfered by some script injections which would harm your website or your system.

Comment: is there any other way?7

Comment: You can sanitize your HTML string before using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify, let me mention it in my answer too :D @RunjieChen

Answer (score 0):

You can use html-react-parser package

This is how your code will look like

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/get-post?id=${pid}`)
        .then(res => setPostData(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.containerPadding}>
                <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.blackLine}>
    
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
                        <div>
                            <h1>{postData.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h1></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.postInformationContainer}>
                        <div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>{parse(postData?.post_stream?.posts[0]?.cooked)}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' like everyone else.

And I need to register the tags to use.

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

          <div
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(
                view_inner ?? '<div>Unable to get data.</div>',
                {
                  FORCE_BODY: true,
                  ADD_TAGS: ['style'],
                  ADD_ATTR: ['target'],
                  ALLOWED_TAGS: [
                    'span',
                    'div',
                    'link',
                    'table',
                    'thead',
                    'tr',
                    'th',
                    'tbody',
                    'td',
                  ],
                },
              ),
            }}
          />
```